# Django HTML: how do I make a "go home" link?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates

Here is the file structure of my project.

[image]

I am adding a link in testpage.html, and I want it to take the user back to the root directory (http://127.0.0.1:8000 on localhost server) which is configured to use index.html as the homepage under pages > templates > index.

testpage.html is below. the link is in line 3 (currently empty):

```
 <h1 class='list'>Classes</h1>
        {% if mydata %}
        <a href="">Go home</a>
        {% endif %}
       {% for k in mydata  %}
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <th>Team</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>ClassCode</th>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <td>{{k.Team}}</td>
                <td>{{k.Name}}</td>
                <td>{{k.ClassCode}}</td>
            
            </tr>
            
            
        </table>
        {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your app urls.py, you should have something like

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    #...
    path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
    #...
]
```

then in the template, you can have

```
<a href="{% url 'home' %}">Go home</a>
```

here `home` is the name of the path.